# Target element in galleria on ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, galleria

I am trying to manipulate one particular element which contains a piece of text, I want to wrap it in an href, although I am using css background red to prove targeting of the element.

I am using Galleria 1.2.8 and I currently have a function which fires on ajaxComplete and works.

This is the current working function:

```
// dynamically create data-links for all gallery items
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#galleria a').each(function() {
        var $href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).children().attr('data-link',$href);
    });
    $('.galleria-info-description:contains("NN")').css('background', 'red');  
});
```

The last line is the part of that function is not working.

This is the simplified basic block of html which is created dynamically:

```
 <div class="galleria-container">
    <div class="galleria-stage">
    </div>
    <div class="galleria-thumbnails-container">
    </div>
    <div class="galleria-info">
       <div class="galleria-info-text">
          <div class="galleria-info-description">
              NN Contemporary Art
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="galleria-info-link">
       </div>
       <div class="galleria-info-close">
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried quite a few variations, creating a variable to hold the content and manipulate that. Targeting the class by drilling down through several of its parents, nothing seems to work. I can, on ajaxComplete, remove the #galleria id from the page completely, just cannot seem to get the specific element returned in an object.

TIA.

Comment: Are you sure Galleria has been built when the last selector is used? Could you point out when and where you initialize galleria?

Comment: It's below this block of code, towards the footer. You can actually see the code here: http://dev.jessicaharby.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's a bit clunky, but I checked the galleria documentation here:
http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#retrieval

I have now added this code just before the galleria init:

```
Galleria.ready(function(options) {
$targetElem = ( this.getData([10]));
$targetElem.description = '<a href="http://www.nncontemporaryart.org/exhibitions/guests-   hosts" target="_blank">NN Contemporary Art Northampton</a>';
});
```